# Uploading zip file to Media Library and enabling "unpacking" results in an error

Tags: content-editor, media-library

## The issue

When I use the **Upload files (advanced)** feature of the Media Library to upload a zip file with images in it (Sitecore 8.1 Update 3) and check the box to **Unpack ZIP archives**, uploading fails with the error:

```
An error occured while uploading:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

[image: image of error message]

## What I've tried

I checked the logs, but found no messages at the time that the error occurs (or that looked related).

I have tried tracing the network requests, but everything responds with `200`s and there are no error messages in the responses.

I saw [this article about handling the upload with SPE](https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2015/09/15/Sitecore-8-Bug-Uploading-Images-in-Zip-Files/), but we don't currently have that installed (and we want content editors to be able to perform the functionality, too).

I saw [this article with a promising-looking fix](https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/bug-sitecore-media-library-issue-with-unpacking-zip-archives/), but the change was already applied in my version of Sitecore.

I tried updating security to give Everyone Full Control to the entire Website directory (and descendants).

Comment: Have you checked the log files to see what the stack trace of the error is?

Comment: @RichardSeal, sorry, I forgot to mention that I checked the logs and--even though `DEBUG` is enabled--there are no messages occurring at that time.

Comment: Do you have `__MACOSX` folder in your zip file? Sitecore zipping mechanism doesn't work well with them. If yes, try extracting the archive on PC, remove `__MACOSX` folder and zip again.

Comment: @MarekMusielak, yep, this is the issue. Sitecore has logged it as a bug and I'm looking into whether there is a possible code solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Warning

Don't do this unless you have a *really* good reason to do so. [Marek's answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/14501/342) is better practice. The method I've outlined below works, but--as you'll see--requires decompiling a lot of internal Sitecore code. This will mean, at the very least, a lot of testing when upgrading Sitecore in the future and, at the worst, significant rewriting.

## You've been warned

So here's how you do it! The underlying problem is that the `Sitecore.Zip` library doesn't handle the property files that are in the `__MACOSX` folder of zip files generated on Macs. Luckily, if you're using .NET Framework 4.5 or newer, you can use Microsoft's `System.IO.Compression` library for handling the files and everything works fine. Everything below is to replace Sitecore's implementation with Microsoft's.

### First, you need to decompile three pipelines:

#### `Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckExtension`

This iterates the contents of the zip file and looks for any restricted file extensions.

**Note: this one is only necessary if you've added [Sitecore's Upload Filter](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_hardening/configuring/secure_the_file_upload_functionality#_The_upload_filter).**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload;

namespace Custom.Processors.UiUpload
{
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// NOTE: THIS CLASS IS DECOMPILED FROM Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckExtension.
    ///     THE ONLY SUBSTANTIVE CHANGE IS TO USE System.IO.Compression INSTEAD 
    ///     OF Sitecore.Zip FOR THE ZIP FILE HANDLING.
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class CustomCheckExtension : UploadProcessor
    {
        private bool _isAllowed;

        private string _extensions;

        public CustomCheckExtension(string allowed, string blocked)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(allowed))
            {
                this._isAllowed = true;
                this._extensions = allowed.Replace(" ", "").ToLower();
                return;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(blocked))
            {
                this._isAllowed = false;
                this._extensions = blocked.Replace(" ", "").ToLower();
            }
        }

        private List<string> PrepareExtensions(string csvExtensions)
        {
            string[] strArrays = csvExtensions.Split(',');
            List<string> strs = new List<string>();
            string[] strArrays1 = strArrays;
            for (int i = 0; i < strArrays1.Length; i++)
            {
                strs.Add(strArrays1[i]);
            }
            return strs;
        }

        public void Process(UploadArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._extensions))
            {
                return;
            }
            List<string> strs = this.PrepareExtensions(this._extensions);
            foreach (string file in args.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile item = args.Files[file];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item?.FileName))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (IsUnpack(args, item))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var archive = new ZipArchive(item.InputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
                        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries.Where(e => !e.FullName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("__MACOSX")))
                        {
                            string str = Path.GetExtension(entry.Name.ToLower()).TrimStart('.');
                            bool flag = strs.Contains(str);
                            if (this._isAllowed && flag || (this._isAllowed || !flag) && (!this._isAllowed || flag))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Concat("<script type=\"text/JavaScript\">alert(\"Uploading files with .", str, " extension is restricted\");</script>"));
                            Log.Audit($"Upload restricted: {entry.Name}", this);
                            new Done().Process(args);
                            args.AbortPipeline();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        item.InputStream.Position = 0;
                    }
                }
                string str1 = Path.GetExtension(item.FileName.ToLower()).TrimStart('.');
                bool flag1 = strs.Contains(str1);
                if (this._isAllowed && flag1 || (this._isAllowed || !flag1) && (!this._isAllowed || flag1))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Concat("<script type=\"text/JavaScript\">alert(\"Uploading files with .", str1, " extension is restricted\");</script>"));
                Log.Audit($"Upload restricted: {item.FileName}", this);
                new Done().Process(args);
                args.AbortPipeline();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### `Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize`

This iterates the contents of the zip file and looks for any file that is larger than the allowed size

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload;

namespace Custom.Processors.UiUpload
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Resolves the folder.
    /// 
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// NOTE: THIS CLASS IS DECOMPILED FROM Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize.
    ///     THE ONLY SUBSTANTIVE CHANGE IS TO USE System.IO.Compression INSTEAD 
    ///     OF Sitecore.Zip FOR THE ZIP FILE HANDLING.
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomCheckSize : UploadProcessor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Runs the processor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        public void Process(UploadArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            if (args.Destination == UploadDestination.File)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (string file in args.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile item = args.Files[file];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item?.FileName))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!IsUnpack(args, item))
                {
                    if (item.ContentLength <= Settings.Media.MaxSizeInDatabase)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    string fileName = item.FileName;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Concat("<html><head><script type=\"text/JavaScript\" language=\"javascript\">window.top.scForm.getTopModalDialog().frames[0].scForm.postRequest(\"\", \"\", \"\", 'ShowFileTooBig(", StringUtil.EscapeJavascriptString(fileName), ")')</script></head><body>Done</body></html>"));
                    args.ErrorText = $"The file \"{fileName}\" is too big to be uploaded. The maximum size for uploading files is {MainUtil.FormatSize(Settings.Media.MaxSizeInDatabase)}.";
                    args.AbortPipeline();
                    return;
                }
                var archive = new ZipArchive(item.InputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
                try
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.GetEntriesWithoutMacOsXDirectoryItems())
                    {
                        if (entry.GetIsDirectory() || entry.Length <= Settings.Media.MaxSizeInDatabase)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        string str = string.Concat(item.FileName, "/", entry.Name);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Concat("<html><head><script type=\"text/JavaScript\" language=\"javascript\">window.top.scForm.getTopModalDialog().frames[0].scForm.postRequest(\"\", \"\", \"\", 'ShowFileTooBig(", StringUtil.EscapeJavascriptString(str), ")')</script></head><body>Done</body></html>"));
                        args.ErrorText = $"The file \"{str}\" is too big to be uploaded. The maximum size for uploading files is {MainUtil.FormatSize(Settings.Media.MaxSizeInDatabase)}.";
                        args.AbortPipeline();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    item.InputStream.Position = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### `Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save`

This is the one that does the real work (unzips the contents and adds them to the media library)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.IO;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload;
using Sitecore.SecurityModel;
using Sitecore.Web;

namespace Custom.Processors.UiUpload
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the uploaded files.
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// NOTE: THIS CLASS IS DECOMPILED FROM Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save.
    ///     THE ONLY SUBSTANTIVE CHANGE IS TO USE System.IO.Compression INSTEAD 
    ///     OF Sitecore.Zip FOR THE ZIP FILE HANDLING.
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomSave : UploadProcessor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Runs the processor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.Exception"><c>Exception</c>.</exception>
        public void Process(UploadArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile item = args.Files[i];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FileName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bool flag = IsUnpack(args, item);
                        if (!args.FileOnly)
                        {
                            var mediaUploader = new CustomMediaUploader
                            {
                                File = item,
                                Unpack = flag,
                                Folder = args.Folder,
                                Versioned = args.Versioned,
                                Language = args.Language,
                                AlternateText = args.GetFileParameter(item.FileName, "alt"),
                                Overwrite = args.Overwrite,
                                FileBased = args.Destination == UploadDestination.File
                            };
                            List<CustomMediaUploadResult> mediaUploadResults;
                            using (new SecurityDisabler()) {
                                mediaUploadResults = mediaUploader.SafeUpload();
                            }
                            string[] fileName = { item.FileName };
                            Log.Audit(this, "Upload: {0}", fileName);
                            foreach (CustomMediaUploadResult mediaUploadResult in mediaUploadResults)
                            {
                                this.ProcessItem(args, mediaUploadResult.Item, mediaUploadResult.Path);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (!flag)
                        {
                            string file = this.UploadToFile(args, item);
                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                args.Properties["filename"] = FileHandle.GetFileHandle(file);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UnpackToFile(args, item);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception1)
                    {
                        Exception exception = exception1;
                        Log.Error(string.Concat("Could not save posted file: ", item.FileName), exception, this);
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Processes the item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        /// <param name="mediaItem">The media item.</param>
        /// <param name="path">The path.</param>
        private void ProcessItem(UploadArgs args, MediaItem mediaItem, string path)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(mediaItem, nameof(mediaItem));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(path, nameof(path));
            if (args.Destination != UploadDestination.Database)
            {
                Log.Info(string.Concat("Media Item has been uploaded to file system: ", path), this);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info(string.Concat("Media Item has been uploaded to database: ", path), this);
            }
            args.UploadedItems.Add(mediaItem.InnerItem);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unpacks to file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        /// <param name="file">The file.</param>
        private static void UnpackToFile(UploadArgs args, HttpPostedFile file)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(file, nameof(file));
            string str = FileUtil.MapPath(TempFolder.GetFilename("temp.zip"));
            file.SaveAs(str);
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(file.InputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
            {
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.GetEntriesWithoutMacOsXDirectoryItems())
                {
                    string uniqueFilename = FileUtil.MakePath(args.Folder, entry.Name, '\\');
                    if (!entry.GetIsDirectory())
                    {
                        if (!args.Overwrite)
                        {
                            uniqueFilename = FileUtil.GetUniqueFilename(uniqueFilename);
                        }
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(uniqueFilename));
                        lock (FileUtil.GetFileLock(uniqueFilename))
                        {
                            FileUtil.CreateFile(uniqueFilename, entry.Open(), true);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(uniqueFilename);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uploads to file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
        /// <param name="file">The file.</param>
        /// <returns>The name of the uploaded file</returns>
        private string UploadToFile(UploadArgs args, HttpPostedFile file)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(file, nameof(file));
            string uniqueFilename = FileUtil.MakePath(args.Folder, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName), '\\');
            if (!args.Overwrite)
            {
                uniqueFilename = FileUtil.GetUniqueFilename(uniqueFilename);
            }
            file.SaveAs(uniqueFilename);
            Log.Info(string.Concat("File has been uploaded: ", uniqueFilename), this);
            return Assert.ResultNotNull(uniqueFilename);
        }
    }
}
```

#### And the config patch to put them in place

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <processors>
            <uiUpload>
                <!-- Again, this one is optional and should only be used if you have the Sitecore Upload Filter configured -->
                <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckExtension, Sitecore.UploadFilter">
                    <patch:attribute name="type">Custom.Processors.UiUpload.CustomCheckExtension,Custom</patch:attribute>
                </processor>
                <processor mode="on" type="Custom.Processors.UiUpload.CustomCheckSize,Custom" patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
                <processor mode="on" type="Custom.Processors.UiUpload.CustomSave,Custom" patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
            </uiUpload>
        </processors>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### Next, you need to decompile some supporting classes

These classes are used by the above pipelines.

#### `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUploader`

This class is used by the `Save` pipeline processor to actually upload the contents of the zip file to the database

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.IO;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.GetMediaCreatorOptions;
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;

namespace Custom.Processors.UiUpload
{
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// NOTE: THIS CLASS IS DECOMPILED FROM Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUploader.
    ///     THE ONLY SUBSTANTIVE CHANGE IS TO USE System.IO.Compression INSTEAD 
    ///     OF Sitecore.Zip FOR THE ZIP FILE HANDLING.
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class CustomMediaUploader : MediaUploader
    {
        public List<CustomMediaUploadResult> SafeUpload()
        {
            List<CustomMediaUploadResult> list = new List<CustomMediaUploadResult>();
            if (string.Compare(Path.GetExtension(this.File.FileName), ".zip", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0 && this.Unpack)
                this.UnpackToDatabase(list);
            else
                this.UploadToDatabase(list);
            return list;
        }

        private void UploadToDatabase(List<CustomMediaUploadResult> list)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(list, nameof(list));
            CustomMediaUploadResult mediaUploadResult = new CustomMediaUploadResult();
            list.Add(mediaUploadResult);
            mediaUploadResult.Path = FileUtil.MakePath(this.Folder, Path.GetFileName(this.File.FileName), '/');
            mediaUploadResult.ValidMediaPath = MediaPathManager.ProposeValidMediaPath(mediaUploadResult.Path);
            var options = new MediaCreatorOptions
                          {
                              Versioned = this.Versioned,
                              Language = this.Language,
                              OverwriteExisting = this.Overwrite,
                              Destination = mediaUploadResult.ValidMediaPath,
                              FileBased = this.FileBased,
                              AlternateText = this.AlternateText,
                              Database = this.Database
                          };
            options.Build(GetMediaCreatorOptionsArgs.UploadContext);
            mediaUploadResult.Item = MediaManager.Creator.CreateFromStream(this.File.InputStream, mediaUploadResult.Path, options);
        }

        private void UnpackToDatabase(List<CustomMediaUploadResult> list)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(list, nameof(list));
            string str = FileUtil.MapPath(TempFolder.GetFilename("temp.zip"));
            string tempFolderPath = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("\\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            this.File.SaveAs(str);
            ZipArchiveEntry lastEntry = null;
            try
            {

                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(str))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.GetEntriesWithoutMacOsXDirectoryItems())
                    {
                        lastEntry = entry;
                        if (!entry.GetIsDirectory())
                        {
                            string filePath = FileUtil.MakePath(tempFolderPath, entry.Name, '/');
                            try
                            {
                                entry.ExtractToFile(filePath, true);
                                var mediaUploadResult = new CustomMediaUploadResult();
                                list.Add(mediaUploadResult);
                                mediaUploadResult.Path = FileUtil.MakePath(this.Folder, entry.Name, '/');
                                mediaUploadResult.ValidMediaPath = MediaPathManager.ProposeValidMediaPath(mediaUploadResult.Path);
                                var options = new MediaCreatorOptions
                                              {
                                                  Language = this.Language,
                                                  Versioned = this.Versioned,
                                                  OverwriteExisting = this.Overwrite,
                                                  Destination = mediaUploadResult.ValidMediaPath,
                                                  FileBased = this.FileBased,
                                                  Database = this.Database
                                              };
                                options.Build(GetMediaCreatorOptionsArgs.UploadContext);
                                mediaUploadResult.Item = MediaManager.Creator.CreateFromFile(filePath, options);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"[CustomMediaUploader] Error trying to save {lastEntry?.FullName} from {this.File.FileName}", ex, this);
            }
            finally
            {
                FileUtil.Delete(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUploadResult`

This class is used to provide the result of the file upload back to the `MediaUploader` and had read-only properties (well, technically the sets are `internal`)

```
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace Musc.Common.Web.Processors.UiUpload
{
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// NOTE: THIS CLASS IS DECOMPILED FROM Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUploadResult.
    ///     THE ONLY SUBSTANTIVE CHANGE IS TO ALLOW ACCESS TO SET THE PROPERTIES.
    /// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class CustomMediaUploadResult
    {
        public Item Item { get; internal set; }
        public string Path { get; internal set; }
        public string ValidMediaPath { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

### Last but not least, you may find these extension methods handy

#### `ZipArchiveExtensions`

This adds an extension method to get the files in the archive that aren't in a `__MACOSX` folder

```
public static class ZipArchiveExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ZipArchiveEntry> GetEntriesWithoutMacOsXDirectoryItems([NotNull] this ZipArchive archive)
    {
        return archive.Entries.Where(e => !e.FullName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("__MACOSX"));
    }
}
```

#### `ZipArchiveEntryExtensions`

This adds an extension method to see whether the current entry is a directory or not

```
public static class ZipArchiveEntryExtensions
{
    public static bool GetIsDirectory([NotNull] this ZipArchiveEntry entry)
    {
        return entry.FullName.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem with zip archives generated on Macs. Sitecore zipping mechanis doesn't work well with zip archives containing `__MACOSX` folder.

As a workaround you can unzip your archive on PC, remove `__MACOSX` folder and zip your files again.

I've tried to look for possible fix for the issue long time ago, but it would require changing multiple Sitecore classes. I don't have a list anymore, but from what I remember, the classes were:

- two `UploadProcessor` classes: `Save` and `CheckSize`,
- replacing original `MediaUploader`.

---

### EDIT: full list of classes which must be changed can be found in Dan's answer

Comment: If you want to update your answer, the list of classes you have to change is in my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Dan. I just pointed from my answer to yours :)